# Как сделать блок выше над остальными?

Tags: html, css

Вот собственно код: http://jsbin.com/uleqom/2/edit
Как блок 3 поднять над остальными без position: absolute и чтоб он не влиял на позицию блоков a,b,c,d ?

```css
.one {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ff8;
}
.one div {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
}
.one .e {
  background: #f8d;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
.two {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}
.two div {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class='q'>1</div>
  <div class='w'>2</div>
  <div class='e'>3</div>
</div>
<div class='two'>
  <div class='a'>a</div>
  <div class='b'>b</div>
  <div class='c'>c</div>
  <div class='d'>d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: код html в примере написан не совсем там где надо. нужно в bosy писать, а там между head и body

Comment: И что значит "поднять над остальными", переместить блок или изменить z-index?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uleqom/6/edit так что-ли ?

Comment: чтоб так http://jsbin.com/uleqom/7/edit, только тут позиционирование относительно тега html, а мне нужно относительно родителя.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uleqom/9/edit

Answer (score 1):

Не position: absolute и не влияет на другие блоки:

```
    .one .e {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```